# Box with border, background image and logo in the middle

Tags: html, css

Building from scratch I managed to create a box with a border.
Doing so I also managed to add the logo to the middle.

Now I want to add background image but it always crashes the complete box.

**My current result:**

```
<div style="
float: left; 
  width: 300px; 
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;  
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;">
    <img style="border-radius: 50%; height: 50%;"src="imageURL" />
</div>
```

[image]

**With background image:**

https://jsfiddle.net/2t3a5wvn/

```
<div style="
    background-image: url("imageurl");
    float: left; 
      width: 300px; 
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 2px solid #000000;
      height: 150px;
      position: relative;  
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;">
        <img style="border-radius: 50%; height: 50%;"src="imageURL" />
    </div>
```

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

Comment: I don't see any use of `background-image` in your current code?

Comment: I copied an older version - I edited the current state. Thanks @Rojo

Comment: The double quotes close your style attribute. I would also advise to use css files instead of inline style.

Comment: I changed it to using single quotes but it did not fix my error. I will later use an css file. https://jsfiddle.net/2t3a5wvn/ @GertB.

Comment: The problem is that the `background: #fff` is overwriting it.
because `background` is shorthand for
`background: #color url("sauce") no-repeat right top;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes or use single quotes in `background-image`. Make sure to remove the `background` property as well.

```
<div style="
    background-image: url('imageurl');
    float: left; 
      width: 300px; 
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 2px solid #000000;
      height: 150px;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;">
        <img style="border-radius: 50%; height: 50%;"src="imageURL" />
    </div>
```

Comment: I changed it to using single quotes , still not showing my background image: https://jsfiddle.net/2t3a5wvn/

Comment: @piguy you overwrite it with `background: #fff;` remove that line

Comment: @GertB. Ahh I see! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -2):

Here you go

the css

```
 <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .box {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        height: 150px;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .center-image {
        position: absolute;
        height: 50%;
        aspect-ratio: 1;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .top-image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: red;
        align-self: start;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
    .info {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: start;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        flex-shrink: 1;
    }
    .name {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .distance {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

the html

```
<div class="box">
    <img class="center-image" />
    <img class="top-image" />
    <div class="info">
        <div class="name">Dein Shopname</div>
        <div class="distance">36 km</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: this would make the layout similar to the one in the image

Comment: Don't just post the code, explain what your answer does. You also re-wrote the whole thing, thats not needed. just answer the question asked

Comment: @GertB. sorry, all this does is make the layout similar to that in the image

Comment: I agree, but you don't need to write the code for them, that way nothing will be learned, they will only copy/paste your answer.

Comment: Thank you @Ki, but I really want to try to build it on my own - your code will help me later if I face any issues.

Comment: @piguy well sorry it seems that i didn't understand the problem is it that `background-image: url('spicySauce');` is not working?